# Getting "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...) is not a function" from time to time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a megamenu to work, according to the documentation you need to add the following scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js"></script>
```

then the following HTML:

```
<div class="nav-header">
    <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
</div>

<div class="nav-menus-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then initialize the menu with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation").navigation();
});
```

I am however getting the following error 50% of the time when I browse my website:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).navigation is not a function @https://tennobattle.com/wiki/Main_Page:268:6
j@https://tennobattle.com/wiki/custom_files/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:29586
g/</k<@https://tennobattle.com/wiki/custom_files/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:29902
 undefined jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:31155
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.delegate() is deprecated load.php:140:200
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated load.php:140:200
```

Does someone know what could be the problem? I have searched a bit and most solutions were that the script order was wrong, I tried that as well without any luck.

If you want, you can browse my website live at: https://tennobattle.com/wiki/Main_Page you will notice from time to time that the dropdown menu stops working.

Comment: I'm getting the deprecation warnings, but not the error. Have you flushed your browser cache to ensure it uses the latest changes?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, but a common cause of errors like this is loading multiple copies of jQuery.